# short content pages-drop down menu gets cut off

Tags: html, css

Having a weird problem on pages that have very little content: a long drop down menu gets cut off at the footer.

[See this live link](http://lisat-alachua2.migwebtech.com/app_pages/view/509)

I keep thinking this has something to do with the body tag or html or something in my css...any quick thoughts?

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Is the overflow:hidden for #outer-wrap necessary? If you take that out, should be fine

Comment: Overflow property does not affect the height.

Comment: yeah, but that fixed the problem

Comment: I tried it, and removing this property does nothing.

Comment: the menu is still cut off?

Comment: My bad. The menu looks fine.

Comment: Thanks to both of you; yes, I need the overflow:hidden for my mobile menu. This is actually the larger problem I am having but I was trying to keep it more simple...If you size that window down you'll see the nav is now accessed from a bar menu at the top . This is the real issue: on short pages my mobile menu is getting cut off and user can't get to all the nav items. Taking out overflow:hidden gives scroll bars when you access the mobile menu.

Comment: How about giving a min-height to your outer-wrap container?

Comment: Nope, min-height to outer container doesn't work. Here's the menu example (http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/01/15/off-canvas-navigation-for-responsive-website/) ; their menu unfortunately has same problem: less content and lots links=no worky; I have commented on the posting hoping the author has a solution.

Comment: I am reposting this question here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22563402/off-canvas-menu-gets-cut-off-on-pages-that-have-very-little-content) with a jsfiddle and the original code from Smashing Magazine; I think that will be easier to get a handle on it.