# off canvas menu gets cut off on pages that have very little content

Tags: css, navigation, responsive-design

I am trying to implement an off canvas menu. I found the example on Smashing magazine and had implemented the menu---it works great except for pages that only have a small amount of content; the items in the slide out menu only appear as far down as the content goes.

Event the example on Smashing Magazine doesn't work properly if you have a short amount of content and a lot of menu items. I have posted a comment over on the Smashing Magazine post but haven't heard back.

[Here's my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p2DFL/)

If you click on the red box, the menu will appear; It doesn't slide out smoothly because I didn't include the javascript (I think my problem is with the css in inner and outer-wrap). The menu should have 11 items but you only see down to 8.

```
#outer-wrap {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
}

#inner-wrap {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
}
```

I really don't want to rebuild the menu some other way. Any assistance is greatly appreciated!! Thank you....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your menu is inside the outer-wrap div with overflow:hidden. that means any element going outside the outerwrap will be "hidden". Just remove the overflow and it should work fine (or put it "visible")

Comment: I have tried that but the menu doesn't fill the space 100% all the way down the page as it used to, it just stops---it does show all nav elements though which is an improvement.

Comment: Ok. then add at your css:
    body, html, form {height:100%}

then keep adding height:100% to your #outer-wrap, #inner-wrap, #nav, and #nav .block and it shoudl always go till the bottom of your browswer: http://jsfiddle.net/p2DFL/2/

Comment: in modified fiddle I just posted I can see once I click on the red square all content going down... even setting the browser to zoom:25%. Add if necesary also height:100% to #nav ul but it shoudn't be necesary.
remember to set an element to "height:100%" ALL parents needs to have same height property so.. it's not eneough to set the body to 100% IF inside the body is a "form" tag.. or outside an html tag... so to be safe I always use html, body, form {height:100%} on my css's when responsive design

Comment: Thank you @Alvaro...can you post link to modified fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

When the viewport width is small enough and your `nav` element's position turned from `relative` to `absolute` which means it jumps out of the `normal flow`. So it's visual dimension doesn't affect other elements at all, which results in the visually incomplete menu.

To fix it you can either give `nav`'s parent div a fixed height or min-height, or set `nav`'s position to `relative` and show it another way.

Okay, maybe you just want the code.

```
var lis = document.querySelectorAll("#nav li");
var minHeight = 41 * lis.length; //41 is the height in pixel of your single menu item
document.getElementById("#nav").style.minHeight = minHeight + 'px';
```